# If $\sqrt[3]x-\sqrt[3]{x-14}=2$, find $x - 1/x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, real-numbers

> $$ \sqrt[3]x-\sqrt[3]{x-14}=2$$
>   Then find $x - \frac{1}{x} = ?$

I've tried to take third power of both sides but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\sqrt[3]x=a,\sqrt[3]{x-14}=b$

$a-b=2, a^3-b^3=14$

**Method**$\#1:$
As $(a-b)^3=a^3-b^3-3ab(a-b)$

$2^3=14-3ab\cdot2\iff ab=1$

**Method**$\#2:$
$$a^3-(a-2)^3=14$$

Comment: Sir, b=a-2, and not a+2.

Comment: it should be a^3−b^3=(a−b)^3 + 3ab(a−b) isn't it?

Comment: @Bbbbbbkkkkkkk, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $(a-b)^3=a^3-b^3-3ab(a-b)\,$ so: $$8 = \left(\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{x-14}\right)^3=x - (x-14) - 3\cdot\sqrt[3]{x\,(x-14)} \cdot 2 = 14 - 6 \sqrt[3]{x\,(x-14)}$$ It follows that: $$x(x-14) = 1 \iff x^2-14x - 1 = 0 \iff x - \frac{1}{x} - 14=0$$

Answer (score 1):

The most direct method:

$\sqrt[3]x-\sqrt[3]{x-14}=2$

$\implies\ \sqrt[3]{x-14}=\sqrt[3]x-2$

$\implies\ x-14=\left(\sqrt[3]x-2\right)^3=x-6(\sqrt[3]x)^2+12(\sqrt[3]x)-8$

$\implies\ 6y^2-12y-6=0$ where $y=\sqrt[3]x$

$\implies\ y=1\pm\sqrt2$

$\implies\ y^3=x=7\pm5\sqrt2$

$\implies\ \dfrac1x=\pm5\sqrt2-7$

Hence $x-\dfrac1x=14$